# SSA/ASS Subtitles - Use frame number instead of time?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitles

I'm trying to construct subtitle tracks from an array of known text strings.  The ASS subtitle format can allow me to burn those strings on screen at known timing intervals.

However, I don't want to reference time, and would rather reference frame number. I.E. Between frames 0 and 5, display "This is the beginning" on screen, and between frames 5 and 10 display "This is the end" on screen.

Any way to do this with the ASS format?  If not, any other methods to burn text on screen in frame intervals instead of time intervals?